# How to find out whether an adjective is for one or two words after it?

Tags: meaning-in-context, adjective-order

Scholars of religion have traced the cross-pollination of **modern Hindu and Buddhist traditions** with the language of “experience”. ([Source](https://academic.oup.com/jaar/article/83/3/599/725097))

Is *modern* an adjective for both *Hindu* and *buddhist* traditions or only for *Hindu tradition*? How can one know that?

Comment: You can't know. At least not from the sentence itself. Only context can tell you for sure. *My* interpretation (based simply on what I've found to be more common in terms of language use) is that it likely applies to both things—but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's somewhat ambiguous.  However, an author who is concerned about possible ambiguity will likely rearrange things to avoid the ambiguity, for example

> Scholars of religion have traced the cross-pollination of Buddhist and modern Hindu traditions with the language of “experience.”

Knowing this, and noticing that the author *didn't* write it that way, we can conclude that probably the adjective refers to both nouns.